# How to list all stacks outputs currently deployed to an AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I currently have three cloudformation stacks:

1. kms-stack
2. vpc-stack
3. sqs-stack

They all export outputs that I can see when I describe that stack but when I run:

```
aws cloudformation list-exports
```

Only the outputs from the vpc stack are printed to the CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of a stack, and the exports from a stack, are not the same thing.

Output of a stack is specified in the Output section.  Each element you include in the output can also be exported if so desired. Exports must be unique within a region.

```
aws cloudformation list-exports
```

will list ALL exported values from all stacks within a region;

So review your cloudformation scripts for each stack and determine if you are actually exporting the values you need.

In the following VPC example, the VPC id will be exported; the IGW will not although both will be displayed in describe-stacks:

```
Outputs:
  VPC:
    Value:
      Ref: VPC
    Export:
      Name: MyVpcID
  InternetGateway:
    Value:
      Ref: InternetGateway
```

Comment: Ahh feel so blind see the error I was making thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `describe-stacks` CLI to get the information. Use the following command:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks
```

CLI details can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html).